# UIAlertController: textfield not returning string

Tags: objective-c, string, uitextfield, uialertcontroller

There is something unexpected I cannot sort out. I have an `alertController` with `textfields`. I try to get the string value of one of them. Everything works fine when the string length is less than 11 characters. Above this threshold, the string is `null`.

Could anyone give me a hint on what there is going on?

Just in case, I put my code below:

```
[alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
        textField.placeholder = @"Name";
        textField.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
        textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    }];

[alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        NSArray *textfields = alertController.textFields;
        UITextField *nameTextfield = textfields[0];
        self.textFieldString = nameTextfield.text;

        NSLog(@"self.textFieldString is: %@", self.textFieldString); // -> this returns a null value when the string length is > 11


    }]];
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you got your solutions ?

Comment: Not yet but I haven't had time to dig for it (sick...). I will let you know. Thx for asking!

Comment: Apparently the problem was related with the "weak" property assignment but I cannot understand why it was working with shorter string length. A mystery. But thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

are you sure `^(UITextField *textField)` and `nameTextfield` is equal to both, make sure you get the current textfield.

```
[alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
    **NSLog(@"%s", textField);**
    textField.placeholder = @"Name";
    textField.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
}];

[alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    NSArray *textfields = alertController.textFields;
    UITextField *nameTextfield = textfields[0];
    **NSLog(@"%s", nameTextfield);**
    self.textFieldString = nameTextfield.text;

    NSLog(@"self.textFieldString is: %@", self.textFieldString); // -> this returns a null value when the string length is > 11


}]];
```

i changed your code , run it ,make sure the address same to each other.

Comment: Yes it is the same address. And it looks like it's fine since there is no problem when my string is less than 12 characters. I only get the error when the string length is beyond this limit. Any other suggestion?

Comment: I have noticed that the textfield text (nameTextfield.text) is okay even with longer strings but only my string attribute (self.textFieldString) remains null when it tries to get a string > 11 characters, as if it was impossible to attribute a string longer than this length

Answer (score 0):

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"title" message:@"message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

[alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
    textField.placeholder = @"Name";
    textField.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
}];

[alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    NSArray *textfields = alertController.textFields;
    UITextField *nameTextfield = textfields[0];
    //        self.textFieldString = ;

    NSLog(@"self.textFieldString is: %@", nameTextfield.text); // -> this returns a null value when the string length is > 11


}]];
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Note :- If You add more textfields then `NSArray *textfields` contains more textfields. So you can use tag for identify textfields.