# NSString remains null when string length is more than 11 characters

Tags: objective-c, null, nsstring, uitextfield, uialertcontroller

I am referring to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41514696/uialertcontroller-textfield-not-returning-string/) but the topic has changed a bit.

I try to get the `string value` of a `UITextfield` presented from an `alertController`. The problem arises when I try to store the string in a `property (NSString)`. Everything works fine when the string length is less than 12 characters but as soon as it goes over this limit, my string property remains `null` although the `textfield.text` returns the string.

Here is a part of the code:

**.h file:**

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSString *textFieldString;
```

**.m file:**

```
[alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
    textField.placeholder = @"Name";
}];

[alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    NSArray *textfields = alertController.textFields;
    UITextField *nameTextfield = textfields[0];
    self.textFieldString = nameTextfield.text;

    NSLog(@"self.textFieldString is: %@", self.textFieldString); // -> this returns a null value when the string length is > 11
    NSLog(@"nameTextfield.text is: %@", nameTextfield.text); // -> this returns the string even when the string length is > 11

}]];
```

I have more than one textfield that is why I have an NSArray. But this does not seem to be the problem since everything is working when the string is < 12 characters. The problem seems to be with my NSString property but I cannot figure out what it's going on...

If anyone could help me...

Comment: Why is `textFieldString` weak?